# Convert horizontal picture to vertical using imagemagick, filling empty space around with black

Tags: imagemagick

I have a horizontal image and i want to create a vertical copy of it for a specific resolution, filling the empty space around it with black. Can this be done with imagemagick and how?

Comment: @don_crissti, yes, that's exactly what i wanna do. Sorry for the bad explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `convert` with `-extent` (and specify background & gravity). Example:
input file `orca.jpg` (lanscape, 300x225)

[image]

If you want to create a portrait image 400x600 preserving the original image size:

```
convert orca.jpg -background black -gravity center -extent 400x600 output.jpg
```

produces:

[image]

Sure, you can also resize the original image to fit a smaller canvas:

```
convert orca.jpg -resize 200 -background black -gravity center -extent 220x400 output.jpg
```

[image]